# Jquery Hover on div in ShadowDom

Tags: jquery, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use jquery's .hover function to display a div on mouse hover over a div created in shadowDom. When I run the code, the hover function never displays. Is it because the object exists in the ShadowDOM?

I've been testing a couple of methods, but all to no avail. Any thoughts? Do I need to add an event listener?

```js
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    myInitCode();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        myInitCode();
    });
}


function myInitCode() {
    var idSection = document.getElementById("centerCol").children[0]; 
    console.log("ID SECTION", idSection); //test to see if ID was found
    var parentNode = document.createElement( 'div' );
    idSection.appendChild(parentNode);
    var shadowRoot = parentNode.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
    console.log("Was Shadowroot made?"); 
    var booyah = document.createElement('div');  
    '<slot></slot>';
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    #booyahPanel {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 30px;
      width: 93px;
      overflow: auto;
      content:url(https://i.ibb.co/NnpdWR2/Button.png);
      object-fit: fill;
      object-position: 50% 50%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="booyahPanel">
    `;

    shadowRoot.appendChild(booyah)
    console.log("Was Shadowroot attached?"); 
    shadowRoot.addEventListener("mouseover", onMouse, false);
    shadowRoot.addEventListener("mouseout", offMouse, false);

      var style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; color: white; position: fixed; top: calc(50% - 50px); right: calc(50% - 50px)";
      var popbox = document.createElement("div");
      popbox.setAttribute("style", style);
      popbox.setAttribute("id", "popbox");
      popbox.innerHTML = "Hello";
      console.log("Did popbox run?");
      /*popbox.id = "popbox";
      popbox.rel = 'stylesheet';
      popbox.type = 'text/css';
      popbox.href= 'style.css'; 
      */
    
    /*function onMouse() {
      //document.getElementById('popbox').style.visibility = "visible";
      shadowRoot.appendChild(popbox);
      console.log("Did onmouse run?");      
    }

    function offMouse() {
      //document.getElementById('popbox').style.visibility = "hidden";
      console.log("Did offmouse run?");
    }
    */

    function onMouse() {
    console.log("Did onMouse run?");
      if ($(".shadowRoot").mouseover == true) {
        document.getElementById('popbox').appendChild(body);
      } 
    };
    
    function offMouse() {
    console.log("Did offmouse run?");
      if ($(".shadowRoot").mouseout == true) {
        document.getElementById('popbox').appendChild(body); 
      }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your events inside your custom component, read more https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events

For example

```js
customElements.define( 'my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super() 
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<p id="1">Click me</p>` 
        this.shadowRoot.addEventListener( 'click', this )
    }
    handleEvent( ev ) {
        console.log( ev.target.id )
    }
} )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. What's the custom component in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In your case try this

```js
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  myInitCode();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    myInitCode();
  });
}


function myInitCode() {
  var parentNode = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(parentNode);
  var shadowRoot = parentNode.attachShadow({
    mode: 'closed'
  });
  console.log("Was Shadowroot made?");
  var booyah = document.createElement('div');
  booyah.id = "booyah";
  booyah.rel = 'stylesheet';
  booyah.type = 'text/css';
  booyah.href = 'style.css';
  //booyah.innerText = 'booyah';
  '<slot></slot>';
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    #booyahPanel {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 30px;
      width: 93px;
      overflow: auto;
      content:url(https://i.ibb.co/NnpdWR2/Button.png);
      object-fit: fill;
      object-position: 50% 50%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="booyahPanel">
    `;

  shadowRoot.appendChild(booyah)
  console.log("Was Shadowroot attached?");
  shadowRoot.addEventListener('mouseover', createPopbox)
}


function createPopbox() {
  console.log("Why isn't this code fuckin executing?");
  if (document.getElementById('popbox')) {
    return;
  }
  var style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; color: white; position: fixed; top: calc(50% - 50px); right: calc(50% - 50px)";
  var popbox = document.createElement("div");
  popbox.setAttribute("style", style);
  popbox.setAttribute("id", "popbox");
  popbox.innerHTML = "Hello";
  document.body.appendChild(popbox);
  console.log("Did popbox run?");
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the event listener caused the button to not show up. I've been playing around with the updated code in the post.

Comment: Do you want to add popbox to the body? or what? Sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: Yea, the popup box will show when the mouse hovers over the BooyahPanel. I keep getting a return null error.

Comment: Is it possible to show visibility on mouseover and mouseout? When I try it, i keep getting a return null error.       document.getElementById('popbox').style.visibility = "visible";

Comment: Show your code please where you use getElementById('popbox')

Comment: I think you didn't add `popbox` anywhere. You should add `popbox`  with appendChild